# Property coordinates

Tags: coordinates, propertyinfo

I have 14,000 Property coordinates and want to move them to the (c)kerbside or (sidewalk) footpath.
Is their a way to do this?
Maybe the Property coordinates moved to the Closest road Boundaries (polyline?) +3metres
regards michael

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fit a line to the street and then find a perpendicular line to the property coordinate.  The place where the two interest should be what you need?